# How to determine whether a TransparentProxy points to a valid instance

Tags: .net, proxy, appdomain

Is there a way to determine whether a `TransparentProxy` is pointing to a valid reference?

I have `IPlugin`. I create a new AppDomain, load the assembly with an implementation of `IPlugin`, and create an instance of that implemenation. I receive a `IPlugin`, but under the covers its `TransparentProxy`. If I unload the secondary AppDomain, the instance of `IPlugin` (the one that the proxy points to) is gone. But the proxy is still pointing there. My program crashes (with no exceptions) when I try to access the proxy.

Psudeocode:

```
var domain = CreateDomain("domain");
var assembly = domain.LoadAssembly("myAssembly");
var plugin = domain.CreateObject("MyPlugin") as IPlugin; 
// plugin is really a TransparentProxy to a MyPlugin

if (plugin != null)
    plugin.DoSomething("123");

UnloadDomain(domain);

if (plugin != null) // Still evaluates to TRUE!
    plugin.DoSomething("123"); // Program crashes with no exceptions
```

Comment: You should get a RemotingException, not a crash. Still, I would like to know the answer to this question too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since no one has suggested a proper answer, you could try this:

```
public static bool IsValidReference(MarshalByRefObject obj)
{
    try {
        obj.Equals(null);
        return true;
    } catch (RemotingException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: i didn't receive any exceptions. my app just dies.